# How can I create a stepper progreesbar for traversing through different screens using android jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-progressbar

I have 5 onboarding screens from which I have to navigate from screen1 to eventually screen 5. So when I reach at screen 5 it should display this picture. [image]

But for the first screen everything should be white except the first circle will be like this [image]

With a line [image]
connected to it and then followed by [image] connected to the other side of this line. And then when we reach on second screen this [image: enter image description should here] should turn into a green line[image] while the first circle turning into a green circle [image] and a correct icon [image] on it. So the flow continues as follows as we move forward to the screens and if we go backward, the screens should change into white line. I am attaching the screenshot of what I am trying to achieve.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eA6ix.png) [image] So I am using jetpack compose and I tried to connect all the separate parts into one but I couldn't achieve what I wanted This is the code I tried to display the progressbar of the first screen.

```
Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy((-15).dp, Alignment.Start),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,modifier = Modifier
        .width(327.dp)
        .height(15.dp)
        .padding(start = 18.dp, end = 15.dp)) {
    
    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.indicator ),
        contentDescription ="indicator")
    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.line),
        contentDescription = null)
    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.stepcircle),
        contentDescription =null)
    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.line),
        contentDescription = null)
    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.stepcircle),
        contentDescription =null)
    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.line),
        contentDescription = null)
    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.stepcircle),
        contentDescription =null)

    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried finding any library for this?

Comment: I have but, couldn't find one. Do you know any library?

Comment: this is close [github](https://github.com/maryamrzdh/compose-stepper) but not what you require, I had somewhat similar implementation so I had to write it myself.